# Angular7 'length' is missing in type '[]'

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

I am pulling some data with simple values and show it in footer
and getting this.

> ERROR in src/app/layout/customer/customerform/customerform.component.ts(25,7): error TS2322: Type 'Footer' is not assignable to type 'Footer[]'.
>     Property 'length' is missing in type 'Footer'.

**Component.ts**

```
  footers: Footer[];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getFooter();
    console.log(this.footers);
  }

  getFooter() {
    this.bone.getFooter().subscribe( actions => {
      this.footers = actions.payload.data() as Footer;
    });
  }
```

**model.ts**

```
export interface Footer {
  id?: string;
  color?: string;
  bg?: string;
  text?: string;
}
```

**service.ts**

```
 getFooter() {
    return this.footerCollection.doc("style").snapshotChanges();
  }
```

Comment: declare footers as `footers:Footer[]=[]` else the variable is null

Comment: shouldn't it be: ```this.footers = actions.payload.data() as Footer[];```

Comment: once I remove `Footer[]` from `footers;`, is shows me `undefined` value

Answer (score 2):

You need to change casting from `Footer` to `Footer[]`:

```
this.footers = actions.payload.data() as Footer[];
```

---

You need to initialize `footers` to not to get `undefined` error:

```
footers: Footer[] = [];
```

Comment: its `undefined`, once I check what I get in `this.footers` through `console.log(this.footers)`,

Comment: It's undefined  becasue you did not initialize `this.footers`. Edited the answer

Comment: `<p>{{footers.text}}</p>` or have to use `*ngFor`. or can you help me out with snippet?

Comment: Please create a project  at [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/) and I'll gladly try to help.

Comment: The project seems incomplete. `Footer` class and `this.bone` is not defined